# Can't get google maps to display with XSLT and JQuery Mobile

Tags: google-maps, xslt, jquery-mobile

I have been set a task, part of which is to display a google map on pages im creating using XSLT and JQuery mobile. I've looked at a few examples similar to what I'm doing but they just won't seem to work for me. Here are the lines involved in my current attempt, can anyone tell me why the map won't appear? My expected result is for the google map to display in the cell of the table defined on each restaurant page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!-- DWXMLSource="restaurants.xml" -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<!--<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
</xsl:text>-->
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
#map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<title>Choose a restaurant</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
}
</script>




</head>

<body onload="initialize()">


<div data-role="page" id="frontpage">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Choose a Restaurant</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant">
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
<h3><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - <xsl:value-of select="cuisine"/> - Price range:-  <xsl:value-of select="price"/></h3>
<table border="0"   cellpadding="10"> 
<tr>
<td><p><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute></img></p></td>
```

#Click Here for More Info

```
</div>
</xsl:for-each> 

</div>  
<!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Choose a Restaurant</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->



<div data-role="page" id="rest1">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest1']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest1']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute </img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
<td><div id="map_canvas" ></div></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest1']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest2">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest2']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest2']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute></img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest2']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest3">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest3']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest3']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute>  </img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest3']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest4">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest4']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest4']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute>   </img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest4']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>


<div data-role="page" id="rest5">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest5']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest5']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute> </img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest5']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->  

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest6">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest6']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest6']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute>   </img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest6']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest7">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest7']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest7']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute></img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest7']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest8">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest8']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest8']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute></img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest8']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each> 
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest9">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest9']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest9']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute></img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest9']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="rest10">

<div data-role="header">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest10']">
<h1><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h1>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest10']">
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding = "5">
<tr>
<td><img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="picture" /></xsl:attribute></img></td>
<td>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/monday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/tuesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/wednesday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/thursday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/friday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/saturday"/></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="opening_times/sunday"/></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Christmas Offer:- <xsl:value-of select="christmas_offer"/></p></td>
<td><center><p>Overall Rating:- <xsl:value-of select="rating"/></p></center></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</xsl:for-each>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<xsl:for-each select="listing/restaurant[restid ='rest10']">
<h4><xsl:value-of select="name"/></h4>
</xsl:for-each>
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div>

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT code isn't well-formed XML document (hint: something is missing at the end). Also, you haven't provided a source XML document and it is impossible to run the transformation on it. Finally, you haven't specified what is the expected result from the transformation. Please, edit the question and provide all this missing information.

Comment: Is that all the information you need?

Comment: @_Fred Ferguson: You need to do your "homework" before posting a question. A part of this is to isolate the problem and to provide a complete, but *as small as possible* code example that reproduces the problem. Posting 800 lines of code (BTW having code files this big is a good atipattern!), separated in two different parts and whose combination isn't well-formed XML -- this isn't going to attract people and motivate them to consider answering the question. Not to mention that the source XML document is still not provided, and the same goes for explaining what the transformation must perform.

Comment: Fred, I second @Dimitre. Just looking through the posted XML is dizzying. Clean up both documents, remove all data that is not pertinent to your error and let us know what error you are getting. What's showing up? What's not?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript has the function call `document.getElementById("map_canvas")` within your initialize code; considering the part of the stylesheet that generates that element is within a `<xsl:for-each>` block, it's likely that your output HTML has multiple such elements with the same ID.

It's difficult to know exactly what effect that'll have, but it's extremely likely that it's not going to be able to find the correct `div` element to put the map on. It will either return only one of them, or it'll fail with an error indicating that it's ambiguous. Either way, you're not going to get maps where you want them.